# Rails4: Form-Update via Ajax not working -> Template error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I am trying to update a section in a form when the user enters a valid date. CoffeeScript is
initiating a call to the controller and the controller starts a '.js.erb' action for rendering 
a form partial. What I want is to supply the user-entered date to a 'autocomplete' field, so
only values with a certain validity date will be returned and offered...

See code below:

flights.s.coffee:

```
$ -> 
    $("#flight_f_date").focusout ->
        $.ajax
            url: "/flight/populateAircraftsSelection"
            data:
                f_date: $('#flight_f_date').val()
            dataType: "script"
```

My controller function looks like:

```
def populateAircraftsSelection

  puts "AircraftsSelection" + params[:f_date.to_s]

  @flight_date = params[:f_date].to_s

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end 
end
```

populateAircraftsSelection.js.erb:

```
$("#flight_test").html("<%= escape_javascript render partial: 'test', :locals => { flight: @flight, flight_date: @flight_date  }  %>");
```

and the _test.htnl.erb partial

```
<div id="#test">
    <%= f.label :aircraft_id, "Kennzeichen" %><br>
    <%= f.hidden_field :aircraft_id %>
    <%= f.autocomplete_field :helper_registration_field ,   
                             autocomplete_aircraft_registration_flights_path(:flight_date => 
                             @flight_date.to_s), 
                             :update_elements => { :id => '#flight_aircraft_id', :acfttype => 
                             '#flight_helper_aircraft_field' } %>
</div>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#     
<Class:0x007fee2cb62c28>:0x007fee298a0ec0>):
    1: <div id="#test">
    2:
    3:
    4:  <%= f.label :aircraft_id, "Kennzeichen" %><br>
    5:                      <%= f.hidden_field :aircraft_id %>
    6:
    7:                  <%= f.autocomplete_field :helper_registration_field , 
 autocomplete_aircraft_registration_flights_path(:flight_date => @flight_date.to_s),

app/views/flights/_test.html.erb:4:in    
`_app_views_flights__test_html_erb__1386346884294841760_70330389540980'
  app/views/flights/populateAircraftsSelection.js.erb:1:in 
 `_app_views_flights_populate_ircrafts_election_js_erb__2604210186479166916_70330440189180'
   app/controllers/flights_controller.rb:179:in `populateAircraftsSelection'
```

I thought 'f' must be know, because I am adding this partial into a bigger form where 'f' is
already known.....

What I am doing wrong? Or: is there a much better way to update a a clue inside a form after
user interaction.....?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide...

Dirk

Comment: please post the total view

Comment: What do you need from the view to see? View is nearly 200 lines big.... Is it ok to post an excerpt?

Comment: f seems form_for object and when you render parital after ajax success you dont have that form for object that's why you getting that error.

Comment: OK, thanks - but what can I for to correct....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found a trick on my own - using a session variable. I know, it's dirty, and has nothing to do with AJAX as it was designed, - but it works...
Only problem to distinguish in two or three location when to use params and when to use session. But
still using AJAX and Coffeescript to initiate this kind of a call....